# How to build backref with both associatition object and secondaryjoin?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I need some models for instance following:

- Work - e.g. works of literature.
- Worker - e.g. composer, translator or something similar has contribution to work.

Thus, a `'type'` field is required to distinguish workers by division of work. As SQLAlchemy's documentation, this case can benifit from **association object** like following:

```
class Work(base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    description = Column(Text)

class Worker(base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    description = Column(Text)

class Assignment(base):
    work_id = Column(Integer, Foreignkey('work.id'), primary_key=True)
    worker_id = Column(Integer, Foreignkey('worker.id'), primary_key=True)
    type = Column(SmallInteger, nullable=True)
```

Nonetheless, how to take advantage of **backref** and **alternatvie join condition** for building relation immediately to implement that each `Work` object can retrieve and modify corresponding `Worker`(s) via different attributions for distinction. For example:

```
work = session.query(Work).get(1)
work.name
>>> 'A Dream of The Red Mansions'
work.composers
>>> [<Worker('Xueqin Cao')>]
work.translators
>>> [<Worker('Xianyi Yang')>, <Worker('Naidie Dai')>]
```

Vice versa:

```
worker = session.query(Worker).get(1)
worker.name
>>> 'Xueqin Cao'
worker.composed
>>> [<Work('A Dream of The Red Mansions')>]
worker.translated
>>> []
```

Adding `secondaryjoin` directly without `secondary` specified seems not feasible, besides, SQLAlchemy's docs notes that:

> When using the association object pattern, it is advisable that the association-mapped table not be used as the secondary argument on a relationship() elsewhere, unless that relationship() contains the option viewonly=True. SQLAlchemy otherwise may attempt to emit redundant INSERT and DELETE statements on the same table, if similar state is detected on the related attribute as well as the associated object.

Then, is there some way to build these relations elegantly and readily ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's three general ways to go here.

One is, do a "vanilla" setup where you have "work"/"workers" set up without distinguishing on "type" - then, use `relationship()` for "composer", "composed", "translator", "translated" by using "secondary" to `Assignment.__table__` along with custom join conditions, as well as `viewonly=True`.  So you'd do writes via the vanilla properties only.  A disadvantage here is that there's no immediate synchronization between the "vanilla" and "specific" collections.

Another is, same with the "vanilla" setup, but just use plain Python descriptors to give "composer", "composed", "translator", "translated" views in memory, that is, `[obj.worker for obj in self.workers if obj.type == 'composer']`.   This is the simplest way to go.  Whatever you put in the "vanilla" collections shows right up in the "filtered" collection, the SQL is simple, and there's fewer SELECT statements in play (one per Worker/Work instead of N per Worker/Work).

Finally, the approach that's closest to what you're asking, with primary joins and backrefs, but note with the association object, the backrefs are between Work/Assignment and Assignment/Worker, but not between Work/Worker directly.   This approach probably winds up using more SQL to get at the results but is the most complete, and also has the nifty feature that the "type" is written automatically.  We're also using a "one way backref", as Assignment doesn't have a simple way of relating back outwards (there's ways to do it but it would be tedious). Using a Python function to automate creation of the relationships reduces the boilerplate, and note here I'm using a string for "type", this can be an integer if you add more arguments to the system:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy

Base = declarative_base()

def _work_assignment(name):
    assign_ = relationship("Assignment",
                    primaryjoin="and_(Assignment.work_id==Work.id, "
                                    "Assignment.type=='%s')" % name,
                    back_populates="work", cascade="all, delete-orphan")
    assoc = association_proxy("%s_assign" % name, "worker",
                    creator=lambda worker: Assignment(worker=worker, type=name))
    return assoc, assign_

def _worker_assignment(name):
    assign_ = relationship("Assignment",
                    primaryjoin="and_(Assignment.worker_id==Worker.id, "
                                    "Assignment.type=='%s')" % name,
                    back_populates="worker", cascade="all, delete-orphan")
    assoc = association_proxy("%s_assign" % name, "work",
                    creator=lambda work: Assignment(work=work, type=name))
    return assoc, assign_

class Work(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'work'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    description = Column(Text)

    composers, composer_assign = _work_assignment("composer")
    translators, translator_assign = _work_assignment("translator")

class Worker(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'worker'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    description = Column(Text)

    composed, composer_assign = _worker_assignment("composer")
    translated, translator_assign = _worker_assignment("translator")

class Assignment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'assignment'
    work_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('work.id'), primary_key=True)
    worker_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('worker.id'), primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String, nullable=False)

    worker = relationship("Worker")
    work = relationship("Work")

e = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(e)


session = Session(e)

ww1, ww2, ww3 = Worker(name='Xueqin Cao'), Worker(name='Xianyi Yang'), Worker(name='Naidie Dai')

w1 = Work(name='A Dream of The Red Mansions')
w1.composers.append(ww1)
w1.translators.extend([ww2, ww3])

session.add(w1)
session.commit()

work = session.query(Work).get(1)
assert work.name == 'A Dream of The Red Mansions'
assert work.composers == [ww1]
assert work.translators == [ww2, ww3]

worker = session.query(Worker).get(ww1.id)
assert worker.name == 'Xueqin Cao'
assert worker.composed == [work]
assert worker.translated == []

worker.composed[:] = []

# either do this...
session.expire(work, ['composer_assign'])

# or this....basically need composer_assign to reload
# session.commit()

assert work.composers == []
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Futher, it seems that it was losing benefit from lazy loader and cannot remove `Work` from one `Worker`'s assignment via association proxy. How to overcome or improve this case ?

Comment: ive updated it to support deletion of Assignment via item removal. but it still requires that the other side be expired/refreshed for it to show the new data.